# I want to log system calls programmatically

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I want to log system calls programmatically. What is the best way of doing so? Should I use the source code of strace for my custom program. Should I use ptrace? Does strace internally uses ptrace too? Also I don't want slowdowns due to logging system calls. How much penalty strace or ptrace have? Can they be easily used for multithreaded applications?

Answer (score 1):

Use dtrace. Dtrace is explicitly meant for production-use with minimum performnce impact. It provides scripting support with D-language so you can write your own scripts to capture anything and everything.

Comment: Initial setup needs root level permissions. User needs different se tof permissions to be able to capture data. Depends on what data you need to capture.

Comment: Vikas Nalwar, is there dtrace for Linux? User101.., marked question with `Linux` tag.